# Change the background color of a row in a JTable

Tags: java, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I have a JTable with 3 columns. I've set the `TableCellRenderer` for all the 3 columns like this (maybe not very effective?).

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
     myJTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setCellRenderer(renderer);
 }
```

The `getTableCellRendererComponent()` returns a Component with a random background color for each row.
How could I change the background to an other random color while the program is running?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One way would be store the current colour for each row within the model. Here's a simple model that is fixed at 3 columns and 3 rows:

```
static class MyTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {

    List<Color> rowColours = Arrays.asList(
        Color.RED,
        Color.GREEN,
        Color.CYAN
    );

    public void setRowColour(int row, Color c) {
        rowColours.set(row, c);
        fireTableRowsUpdated(row, row);
    }

    public Color getRowColour(int row) {
        return rowColours.get(row);
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
        return String.format("%d %d", row, column);
    }
}
```

Note that `setRowColour` calls `fireTableRowsUpdated`; this will cause just that row of the table to be updated.

The renderer can get the model from the table:

```
static class MyTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        MyTableModel model = (MyTableModel) table.getModel();
        Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        c.setBackground(model.getRowColour(row));
        return c;
    }
}
```

Changing a row's colour would be as simple as:

```
model.setRowColour(1, Color.YELLOW);
```

Comment: why model should know about the colors? is that an mvc breaking?

Answer (score 31):

Resumee of Richard Fearn's answer , to make each second line gray:

```
jTable.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer()
{
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
    {
        final Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        c.setBackground(row % 2 == 0 ? Color.LIGHT_GRAY : Color.WHITE);
        return c;
    }
});
```

Comment: You are right, This is working but why this only works for first 5 columns? any idea?

Comment: @Sahan because beyond 5th column there might be a custom cell-renderer.

Comment: i tried this olivier, but after i used that code above the effect is that i unable to use .setSelectionBackground(Color.yellow); any longer.... :(

Comment: @gumuruh you can set the selection color in the renderer as well by using the provided isSelected argument

Comment: this works right but I have also set entire row selection enabled for JTable. Looking for a solution working correctly with JTable.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);

Answer (score 16):

The other answers given here work well since you use the same renderer in every column.

However, I tend to believe that generally when using a JTable you will have different types of data in each columm and therefore you won't be using the same renderer for each column. In these cases you may find the [Table Row Rendering](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) approach helpfull.

In essence it suggests to override JTable's prepareRenderer method.

```
JTable table = new JTable(...)
{
    public Component prepareRenderer(
        TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column)
    {
        Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);

        //  add custom rendering here

        return c;
    }
};
```

Comment: I agree. It seemed to me that `TableModel` is supposed to hold table data. Rendering should be performed somewhere else. The linked article is enlightening, thank! :)

Comment: I like the idea that you can replace cell renderers and still have consistent row coloring.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically as simple as repainting the table.  I haven't found a way to selectively repaint just one row/column/cell however.

In this example, clicking on the button changes the background color for a row and then calls repaint.

```
public class TableTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final Color[] rowColors = new Color[] {
                randomColor(), randomColor(), randomColor()
        };
        final JTable table = new JTable(3, 3);
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new TableCellRenderer() {
            @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
                    Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
                    int row, int column) {
                JPanel pane = new JPanel();
                pane.setBackground(rowColors[row]);
                return pane;
            }
        });
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JButton btn = new JButton("Change row2's color");
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                rowColors[1] = randomColor();
                table.repaint();
            }
        });

        frame.add(table, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(btn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static Color randomColor() {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        return new Color(rnd.nextInt(256),
                rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The call to `getTableCellRendererComponent(...)` includes the value of the cell for which a renderer is sought.

You can use that value to compute a color. If you're also using an AbstractTableModel, you can provide a value of arbitrary type to your renderer.

Once you have a color, you can `setBackground()` on the component that you're returning.