# Change row color based on column value using Java PaginationUI swing

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to change the row color based on the last column's value

Following is the code used:

```
PaginationUI pageUI =new PaginationUI();
        this.dialog = new JDialog(jFrame, csvName, true);
 pageUI.setCurrentPageIndex(1);
        pageUI.setItemsPerPage(itemsPerPage);
        pageUI.setHeader(header);
        pageUI.setData(data);   

        pageUI.paintPaginatedData();
```

Plz help. I need to check the last value of the "data" Arraylist. Depending on that if value is "abc" ,need to change the value of that row.

I went through 
[Change the background color of a row in a JTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875607/change-the-background-color-of-a-row-in-a-jtable)

and did most of the things suggested therein, except the MyTableCellRenderer, which I did not understand where that is implemented.

Comment: PaginationUI is your class or any library ? Pagination and colouring a table row has no connection. Can you show us table code ?

Comment: TableCellRenderer is important part of cell coloring ;)

Answer (score 0):

> i  am trying to change the row color based on the last column's value

See [Table Row Rendering](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) for one solution that works by overriding the `prepareRenderer(...)` method of the `JTable`, so you don't need to provide a custom renderer for each data type in the table.

> I need to check the last value of the "data" Arraylist

No, you should NOT be referencing the ArrayList. You should only ever reference the data in the `TableModel`.

> and did most of the things suggested therein

Then it should work. The problem is with your code. Post your `SSCCE` that demonstrates your problem if the above solution doesn't help.