# Java Changing the color of a certain row in JTable

Tags: java, swing, colors, jtable, row

ANSWER:
Im not allowed to post answers... thumbs up stackoverflow!!!

But here it is:

Holy freakin'....

I made it, actualy it was easier than i have thought....

Here's my solution:

```
tbl_needaction = new javax.swing.JTable()
    {
        public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column)
        {
            Date d = new Date();
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
            java.util.Date acdate = null;
            Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);

            //  Color row based on a cell value

            if (!isRowSelected(row))
            {
                c.setBackground(getBackground());
                int modelRow = convertRowIndexToModel(row);
                String sd = "";
                sd = (String)getModel().getValueAt(modelRow, 5);
                try {
                    acdate = df.parse(sd);
                } catch (ParseException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(EditApplicationJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

                if (d.compareTo(acdate)>=0){
                        c.setBackground(Color.RED);
                }
            }

            return c;
        }
    };
```

I had to edit this via NotePad++ because NetBeans dosn't allow me to edit the automaticly generated `initComponents()`.

---

QUESTION:
I know, there are lots and lots examples and tutorials for this issue, but none of them seems to work for me....

Im getting data from a sql-database which i show in a JTable. There is a date called "ActionPoint". Now i want to mark every row red where the "ActionPoint" equals today oder is "smaller" than today.

My Code to conpare today with the "ActionPoint" for ebery row in my jTable:

```
for(int row = 0;row < dbApplicantsTableModel.getRowCount();row++) {

            String sd = "";
            sd = (String) dbApplicantsTableModel.getValueAt(row, 5);
            try {
                acdate = df.parse(sd);
            } catch (ParseException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(EditApplicationJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            if (acdate.compareTo(d)<=0){

            }


    }
```

So i should have my "row" which now should be painted red.

Can anyone provide a Method which simply gets a row, and then sets the background of this certain row red?

EDIT:

Now my code looks like this:

```
for(int row = 0;row < dbApplicantsTableModel.getRowCount();row++) {


            String sd = "";
            sd = (String) dbApplicantsTableModel.getValueAt(row, 5);
            try {
                acdate = df.parse(sd);
            } catch (ParseException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(EditApplicationJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            if (acdate.compareTo(d)<=0){
                dbApplicantsTableModel.setRowColour(row, Color.RED);
            }
```

But ist doesnt set any backgrounds red!

Sadly i need a reputation of 10 to post images -.-

Comment: use Table Cell Renderer

Comment: Try writing a `TableCellRenderer`. If you have problems, someone will probably be able to help you.

Comment: Did you see that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875607/change-the-background-color-of-a-row-in-a-jtable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want to mark every row red where the "ActionPoint" equals today oder is "smaller" than today.

Check out [Table Row Rendering](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) for an easy approach to solve this problem. The approach overrides the `prepareRenderer(...)` method of the JTable, so you can add you logic in one place with a simple "if statement".