# How maintain my personal color row in a jtable

Tags: java, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I would like create a jtable with a personal different background color for row.
I write the code but I have a problem, if I select the row or if I scroll the table, my personal color configuration is lost.

Thanks to all

this my code

```
private void go(){

    DefaultTableModel dm = (DefaultTableModel)jtLav.getModel();
    dm.getDataVector().removeAllElements();

    String s_sql = "query";

    try{
        ConnessionePG con = new ConnessionePG("tifas");
        Vector v_res = con.getResult(s_sql);
        con.close();

        Vector v_last_pos = new Vector();
        Vector v_first_pos = new Vector();

        String s_car_prec = "";     
        int i_count_col = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < v_res.size(); i++){
            Hashtable ht = (Hashtable) v_res.get(i);
            String s_car_att = (String) ht.get("carica");

            if (i == 0){
                v_first_pos.add(i);
            }
            else if (s_car_att.equals(s_car_prec) == false){
                v_last_pos.add(i-1);
                v_first_pos.add(i);
            }


            if (i == v_res.size() - 1){
                v_last_pos.add(i);
            }
            s_car_prec = s_car_att;
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < v_res.size(); i++){
            TableColumn tc = new TableColumn();
            tc.setCellRenderer(new MyTableCellRenderer(v_last_pos));

            Hashtable ht = (Hashtable) v_res.get(i);
            System.out.println((String)ht.get("fine"));

            // dati da inserire

            Object o_indice_col = v_first_pos.get(i_count_col);
            int i_indice_col = (int) o_indice_col;



            if (i_indice_col == i){
                i_count_col++;
                ....
            }

            dm.addRow(new Object[]{...
                });
        }

        Enumeration<TableColumn> en = jtLav.getColumnModel().getColumns();
        while (en.hasMoreElements()) {
            TableColumn tc = en.nextElement();  
            tc.setCellRenderer(new MyTableCellRenderer(v_last_pos));
        }

     }
    catch(SQLException e){

    }
}

public class MyTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer implements     TableCellRenderer {

    public MyTableCellRenderer(Vector v){
        v_pos_col = v;
        System.out.println(v_pos_col);


    }
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        setBackground(null);
        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        setText(String.valueOf(value));

        Vector v_col = new Vector();
        v_col.add(new Color(238,218,226));
        v_col.add(Color.white);

        Color col_now = null;

        try{
            Object o_indice_col = v_pos_col.get(i_count_col);
            int i_indice_col = (int) o_indice_col;

            col_now = (Color)v_col.get(i_col % 2);

            setBackground((Color)v_col.get(i_col % 2));
            if (row == i_indice_col){
                i_count_col++;
                i_col++;
            }
        }
        catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){}


        return this;
    }
    int i_col = 0;
    int i_count_col = 0;
    Vector v_pos_col = new Vector();
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change the background color of a row in a JTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875607/change-the-background-color-of-a-row-in-a-jtable)

Answer (score 0):

```
Vector v_col = new Vector();
```

You area creating a new Vector every time the getTableCellRendererComponent() method is invoked. This method is called every time a cell needs to be rendered. Therefore since you create a new Vector, you lose all the Color information.

So you need to create the Vector and assign a Color for every row outside of that method. Then in that method you just reference the Color from the Vector.

I don't understand your exact requirement so I can't give you the exact code, only point you in a different direction.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. I pass to my class an hashtable with each row and its color.

```
public class MyTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {

    public MyTableCellRenderer(Hashtable h){
        ht = h;
    } 
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        setBackground(null);
        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        setText(String.valueOf(value));

        setBackground(ht.get(row));
        return this;
    }

    Hashtable<Reference, Color> ht = null;
}
```